# MySQL Workbench upgrade- do I have to upgrade the connectors as well?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I would like to know if I have to upgrade the MySQL connector as well while upgrading MySQL workbench. Also , do I have to take a backup before doing this ? Saw in few places that backup is only while upgrading the MySQL server. Would appreciate any inputs on this. Thanks !
Below are my existing versions:
MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE-version 8.0.20
MySQL Connector/ODBC 8.0-version 8.0.20
MySQL Installer - Community-version 1.4.33.0

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ you upgrade the connectors?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular thanks for the info. I am new to this , can you please let me know if I have to take a backup of the database or anything else I should check before upgrading the WB and connectors ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're working on a system and you think there might be a risk to your data, take a backup. I don't understand why you're even asking the question. Updating Workbench won't affect your data, but that's really not the point.